# Proof that $\sup\left[\frac{1}{1+nx}\right]=1$, $0<x<1,$ $ n=1,2,3,...$

Tags: real-analysis

proof that $\sup_n\left[\frac{1}{1+nx}\right]=1$, $0<x<1 , n=1,2,3,...$

I tried this:
Clearly, $1>\frac{1}{1+nx}$, let $c$ be $c$ an upper bound. suppose for absurd that $c<1$ then we have: 
$$1<c+cnx<1+cnx<1+nx<1+n.$$

However, I have not reached any absurd 
I've been thinking about the axiom of Archimedes but I do not know how to connect it.

Is this the correct path of proof? thanks...

Comment: You won't get a contradiction for large $n$, because for each fixed $x$ the sequence $x_{n} = \frac{1}{1+nx}$ is *decreasing*. Instead, I suggest that you consider the set 
$$S' = \left\{\frac{1}{1+x} : 0 < x < 1\right\},$$ and show this has the same supremum as your given set.

Comment: Are you after $\sup\left\{\frac1{1+nx}\,\middle|\,x\in(0,1)\wedge n\in\mathbb N\right\}$? Or are you after $\sup\left\{\frac1{1+nx}\,\middle|\,x\in(0,1)\right\}$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: (in light of @JoséCarlosSantos's comment, I should say I have assumed the first case)

Comment: @preferred_anon My guess is that you are right, but I want ot be sure.